# Calculating the ideality factor of a diode

Tags: electric-current, voltage, semiconductor-physics

I am carying out a semiconductor related experiment to calculate the ideality factor of a diode via I-V curves, here is the formula:

[image: Shockley Diode Equation]

[Shockley Diode Formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cinline&space;I=Is%27%5B%5Cexp(%5Cfrac%7BqVa%7D%7BnkT%7D)%5D)

I am trying to find **n** which is the ideality factor. Here is a graph of my data that I am using:
[image: Graph Plot Data]

I am plotting the natural log of the current against voltage and this waveform is what I expect.
I have divided the points into four sections, each section cosist of 25% of the data points. However, I want to only look at segment four for my question because if my query can be solved - it is applicable to all segments here.

I can reformat the equation I shown above into this second one:

[image: Second equation]

[Second Equation](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?%5Cinline&space;%5Chuge&space;%5Cdpi%7B120%7Dln(I)=%7B%5Ccolor%7BRed%7Dln(Is%27)%7D+%7B%5Ccolor%7BEmerald%7D(%5Cfrac%7Bq%7D%7BnkT%7D)%7DVa)

Where I believe the red section is the y-intercept and the green section is the slope!

Now, I would like to show what is really strange. If I zoom into my segment four on my plot and use my second equation, I can get the correct corresponding values:
[image: Zoomed In Segment Four]

Here is an example:
ln(I) = -6.0417 + 1.8665(0.65) = -4.83
And this example corresponds to the correct y-axis value for ln(I). So, I think that second equation where I highlighted the y-intercept and slope is valid.

However! What I **cannot** find nor **understand** is the acquired ideality factor, n

Any time I try to get n, I get vastly unexpected answers ranging from ~14 to ~54 which is not valid! The ideality factor should be around this range: 1 < n < 2
Which I am not getting whatsoever much to my annoyance. I will provide one more formula that is direct to n.

[image: n formula]

[Finding n Directly](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Clarge&space;&space;n=%5Cfrac%7Bq%7D%7BkT%7D%7B%5Ccolor%7BRed%7D%5Cfrac%7BdVa%7D%7Bd(ln(I))%7D)

I believe the section I highlighted as red is the slope of ln(I) against V.

q = 1.602 × 10^-19 coulomb

T = absolute temperature, 300 K (Kelvin)

k = boltzmann's constant, 1.3806488 × 10^-23 joule/K

I would appreciate if anyone could find the dieality factor **n** for me in these four segments, and show me how the workings are done. Thank you.

Comment: Your formula doesn't include parallel leakage or series resistance. I see evidence of both in your graph. Theoretical formula meets practical reality.

Comment: @JohnDoty
Hiya! Thank you for replying, what would be the expanded formulaic expression to include series resistance? I had measured a diode with a 560 Ohm resistor in series.

Comment: You have a (simplified, theoretical) formula for I(V) for the diode. Get I(V) for the resistor from Ohm's law. In series, I is the same for both, V is divided between them. Unfortunately, you get a transcendental equation, so to get a solution you need numerical methods, can't have a formula.